# Constructor with an array of subclasses of an abstract class as a parameter

Tags: c#, constructor, types, constraints, subclassing

I'm working on a player inventory system for a game.

I have a struct *Slot* which has a List<Loot> collection that represents which kinds of items are allowed in it. The abstract class *Loot* is subclassed by all items which are lootable - i.e.: would be valid Content values for the *Slot* struct.

I want to express that a *Slot* can have restrictions on what subclasses of *Loot* it can contain. For instance, if the *Slot* represents an ammo container, I want it to only hold *Loot* subclasses which are ammo containers, like "Quivers" and "Shot Pouches" (which would subclass *Container* somewhere along the line).

**Loot class**

```
public abstract class Loot : GameEntity, ILootable
{
    public int MaxUnitsPerStack { get; set; }
    public int MaxUnitsCarriable { get; set; }
    public int MaxUnitsOwnable { get; set; }

    public void Stack() { }
    public void Split() { }
    public void Scrap() { }
}
```

**Container class**

```
public abstract class Container : Loot
{
    public List<Slot> Slots { get; set; }

    public Container(int slots)
    {
        this.Slots = new List<Slot>(slots);
    }
}
```

**Slot struct**

```
public struct Slot
{
    public Loot Content;
    public int Count;
    public List<Loot> ExclusiveLootTypes;

    public Slot(Loot[] exclusiveLootTypes)
    {
        this.Content = null;
        this.Count = 0;

        List<Loot> newList;
        if (exclusiveLootTypes.Count() > 0)
        {
            newList = new List<Loot>(exclusiveLootTypes.Count());
            foreach (Loot l in exclusiveLootTypes)
            {
                newList.Add(l);
            }
        }
        else { newList = new List<Loot>(); }
        this.ExclusiveLootTypes = newList;
    }
}
```

**PlayerInventory**

```
public struct PlayerInventory
{
    static Dictionary<Slot, string> Slots;

    static void Main()
    {
        Slots = new Dictionary<Slot, string>();

        /* Add a bunch of slots */
        Slots.Add(new Slot(/* I don't know the
                              syntax for this:
                              Quiver, Backpack */), "Backpack"); // Container
    }

}
```

I don't know how to provide the arguments for the Loot subclasses in the *Slot* constructor call in the Main method of the *PlayerInventory* class.

I hope this is clear. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I was able to solve this (and by that, I mean get it to compile) using David Sieler's approach along with some Reflection.

**Slot struct**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;

    public struct Slot
    {
        private Loot _content;
        private int _count;
        public List ExclusiveLootTypes;

        public Loot Content
        {
            get { return _content; }
            private set
            {
                if ((ExclusiveLootTypes.Contains(value.GetType())) && (value.GetType().IsSubclassOf(Type.GetType("Loot"))))
                {
                    _content = value;
                }
            }
        }

        public int Count
        {
            get { return _count; }
            set { _count = value; }
        }

        public Slot(params Type[] exclusiveLootTypes)
        {
            this._content = null;
            this._count = 0;

            List newList;
            if (exclusiveLootTypes.Count() > 0)
            {
                newList = new List(exclusiveLootTypes.Count());
                foreach (Type l in exclusiveLootTypes)
                {
                    newList.Add(l);
                }
            }
            else { newList = new List(); }
            this.ExclusiveLootTypes = newList;
        }
    }
```

**PlayerInventory call to Slot constructor**

```
Slots.Add(new Slot(typeof(Backpack)));
```

Thanks again everyone for the discussion.

Comment: Having done only about a day of thinking on this, Loot instances represent a type of loot. The slot itself has a Count property which represents how many it contains of whatever loot it's holding. I fully expect to change this a dozen times, but that's how it currently works.

Nice TES reference :)

Comment: Sorry, I removed the comment asking if `Loot` instances represent a type of loot or actual loot, because I forgot the idea I had while writing it. So it seems you just need to pass the possible types of loot to the `Slot` constructor as shown in the answer of @Anon, although there are probably *a lot* types of loot that can be placed in a backpack. Have you thought about an interface that types of loot implement which can be placed in a backpack?

Comment: Well, the ExclusiveLootTypes list represents a set of constraints on the slot content, not a range of possible content. If that list had ANY entries, then the slot could ONLY contain items of the type(s) in the list. However, if the list is empty, it could contain anything. I haven't written that routine yet, but that's the idea.

All Loot subclasses can be placed in a backpack - that's one of the things that makes them "loot".

Comment: But you can't put an Daedric Shortsword in a Quiver. ... A `List<Loot>` looks very much like a list of types of loot that can be possible content of a slot, no?

Comment: That's true. Do you think this is something I could solve with proper commenting on that property? Or is it indicative of some more fundamental flaw?

Comment: I find your variable name `ExclusiveLootTypes` very confusing :-) I think you should have a look at the answer of @Cameron MacFarland; it seems like the best solution. On the other hand, I'd probably drop the concept of slots. All slots in a Quiver are equal anyway, right?

Comment: Yes, but not all slots in PlayerInventory are. The "ammo bag" slot only accepts Quiver, ShotPouch, etc. The Quiver itself has slots, and the Quiver object has a type restriction list too, so that any container (of Slots) can globally restrict what items it can contain, or within that container, each Slot can restrict it's own content. That way a slot works equally well for both PlayerInventory, and any bag type. Just seemed more flexible to me.

Comment: I'd say the right arm is a container that can hold a sword, the back is a container that can hold a quiver, and a quiver is a container that can hold arrows. There are two different types of containers: those that limit their content by number (a right hand can hold only 1 sword) and those that limit their content by weight (a backpack can hold any number of items as long as their don't exceed the backpack's weight limit). I personally hate games that have only a limited number of items in a backpack.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the slots? What if you just used a list instead of slots? If a slot is just a list with restrictions then slot could inherit from System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<T>, override InsertItem and add the restriction there.

Comment: I'd say a container is a dictionary that stores the types of loot and the number of actual items of each type in the container, i.e. a `Dictionary<Loot,int>`.

Comment: I think Dictionary is the wrong approach. Instead the Players Inventory should have a RightArmSlot property, of type Slot<IRightArm>, LeftArmSlot of type Slot<ILeftArm> etc. That way each slot is restricted by type directly, rather then all the slots looking like they can hold any type.

Comment: @Cameron: I guess what I'm trying to achieve with the slots is an object which can define various constraints on the kinds of items it can contain, and some functionality for acting on its contents (Stack, Split, Scrap, etc.) A "slot" came to mind as an easy metaphor/container object for all those things. That way I could reuse it for anything that was a container of Loot subclasses. Like a Point(x,y) - it's just easier to think about it as a struct than a mess of List operations.

Comment: Hmmm, ok. Could you achieve the same thing (list operations) with an extension method?

Comment: You can only use those in static classes, right? Wouldn't that limit my flexibility? I know you probably just dropped in to discuss something very specific like syntax, but can you think of a better general approach to the Player-contains-loot items(some of which are themselves containers of loot items) problem?

Comment: Extension methods only operate on instances, not static classes. They are defined in a static class, but they need an instance to work. I'll update my answer to address your design question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to pass an array of `Type` objects to the Slot constructor:

```
public Slot(Type[] exclusiveLootTypes) {
    // be sure and check that each Type is a subtype of Loot!
}

// Construction looks like:
new Slot(new[] {GetType(AmmoContainer), GetType(GemContainer) /* or whatever */});
```

Then write a property setter for `Content` that checks the type of the assigned object, and signals some sort of error if that type isn't contained in ExclusiveLootTypes.

Answer (score 2):

You'd likely find it easier to use `params` in the definition for the Slot constructor:

```
Slot(params Loot[] exclusiveLootTypes)
```

This would allow you to call it like:

```
new Slot(lootItem1, lootItem2, lootItem2 /*...etc*/);
```

Otherwise, you'd need to create an array and pass it in.

Comment: I was hoping to deal with it this way, but this only allows me to use instances, not types. The above new Slot(lootItem1...) would be passing existing instances. I want to pass types, like:

<pre><code>
new Slot(Quiver, ShotPouch);
</code></pre>

where Quiver and ShotPouch would be subclasses of Loot.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your object design needs a slight adjustment.

What if the types of loot items were also interfaces, so for example, all ammo loot items inherit from IAmmoContainer.

Then you could pass in the IAmmoContainer type to restrict the slot.

```
public class Quiver : Container, IAmmoContainer
public class ShotPouch : Container, IAmmoContainer
// ...
new Slot(typeof(IAmmoContainer))
```

**EDIT**

Based on the discussion in the comments, here's how I'd go about designing this system.

The `Loot` class is fine. It represents the base of the loot hierarchy.

Then you define interfaces for the "slots" that an item can occupy. For example:

```
public class LongSword : Loot, IRightHandItem
public class ShortSword : Loot, IRightHandItem, ILeftHandItem
```

Then the PlayerInventory class has "slots" as properties, that are restricted to the appropriate type.

```
public class PlayerInventory
{
    public List<IRightHandItem> RightHandSlot { get; private set; }
    public List<ILeftHandItem> LeftHandSlot { get; private set; }
    // etc...
}
```

Comment: Slots.Add(new Slot(IAmmoBag), "Backpack"); gives the error: "Argument '1': cannot convert from 'System.Type' to (namespace).Loot[]'.

Comment: OK, now I'm really confused. So your slot already contains an instance of the types it can contain? Are you trying to restrict the types added to a slot or pre-initialize the slot with the types already?

Comment: Initially - at this point - no, the slot contains nothing (its Content  variable which holds a Loot type currently == null.) What I'm trying to do is say that if there are ANY items in the List<Loot> ExclusiveLootTypes, then the slot will run validation (when I code it) to ensure that the Content variable ONLY receives item which subclasses one of the Types in List<Loot> ExclusiveLootTypes.

So, I want to create the Slot, and pass a number of subclasses of Loot to it, and then it will add those types to the List<Loot> ExclusiveLootTypes.

Comment: To clarify, I don't want the pass instances of classes to the Slot, I want to pass subclasses of the abstract class Loot. The slot will then ensure that its Content variable will only get filled by instances which are of the subclass(es) listed in the List<Loot> ExclusiveLootTypes.

Comment: @your Edit: I don't think this represents what I'm trying to accomplish. In this approach, a PlayerInventory would have a container (List<IRightHandItem> RightHandSlot) which would hold any number of, say, LongSwords simultaneously. Your version of the RightHand "slot" is more like a bag. I defined a Slot as a container which can ONLY hold ONE item - be it a bag, or a sword, or whatever. That one item it can hold can be restricted by it's type. So the RightHand slot will only hold one item; the TYPE of that item - which subclass of Loot it is, is defined in the Slot's ExclusiveLootType list.

Answer (score 1):

and to combine the previous suggestion to use params, you can use a LINQ extension to convert the params into a List in one step:

```
public Slot(params Type[] exclusiveLootTypes)
{
    this.Content = null;
    this.Count = 0;

    this.ExclusiveLootTypes = exclusiveLootTypes.ToList();
}
```